# When to use \tfrac?

Tags: fractions

When should I use `\tfrac` in formulas? I normally use it in power series, but are there other cases where it looks better with `\tfrac` instead of a full size fraction? Are there any general rules I can follow?

Comment: Hi. Yes, there is `\dfrac`.

Comment: @Sebastiano That doesn't really answer my question. I know about the different fraction styles, but are there any general typographical rules for when the smaller size fraction `\tfrac` should be used in display mode?

Comment: I think this is a matter of opinion. Use `\tfrac` whenever the fraction is not the main part of a formula which has no other fractions.

Comment: Sorry for my bad help.

Comment: Maybe it's also a matter of style.  Of course, style is a matter of opinion, but sometimes there are more or less objective rules.  Is there any "style guide" that addresses this question?

Answer (score 13):

Often it looks better to use `\tfrac` if you are just wanting a numeric fraction as part of an expression, when the display fraction can look a bit spacey. Conversely if the fraction is already a larger expression such as a polynomial the text style fraction can look cramped.  For fractions (in some font families) there is also the possibility of using the font's fraction characters, although they are no so much used in math as they typically don't blend so well with constructed  fractions, but if you only want (say) ½ it's a possibility.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}

(d)frac
\[\frac{1}{2}(x+6)^2\]

tfrac
\[\tfrac{1}{2}(x+6)^2\]


textonehalf
\[\text{\textonehalf}(x+6)^2\]


\bigskip


(d)frac
\[\frac{x^3+5x^2+4}{x^2-2}(x+6)^2\]

tfrac
\[\tfrac{x^3+5x^2+4}{x^2-2}(x+6)^2\]

\end{document}
```